# Passing params in REST calls

Tags: rest, jboss7.x, jax-rs, ejb-3.0, resteasy

I am developing an enterprise app where I need to pass a Session ID in REST requests which will pass the same id in my EJB methods.

The approach I have taken is:

1. Create a Session ID whenever user logins. Use this session id to pass as Header Param in each api except login. (I am still figuring out how to exclude one REST API)
2. Use this session id in the Header and pass it to each EJB. (How to read header param in subsequent Rest calls after interceptor is invoked.)

Can anyone please let me know, if this is the right way to go?

Also, will generating a one-way hash for creating a session token useful rather than sending a auto-generated primary key?

Comment: Why not use `jsessionid`?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a token as a header parameter to identify a logged in user is a common approach. Actually using OAuth is basically the same idea, but adding a standard way of doing so and adding the possibility of expiring/revoking tokens.

About generating a one-way hash, yes. That's the way to go. An auto generated primary key would be a terrible idea. If I log in and I am assigned session 1427, I can be almost 100% sure that there is a 1426 session available for a different user right now. Huge security hole.

Make sure you make those tokens as hard to guess as possible and use https throughout the whole process or you will be exposing your login tokens to eavesdroppers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Dont use autogenerated primary key. If you are using multiple layers of application and dont want to use `JSESSIONID`, use [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) to generate a session-token and use it.